# EditText crashes app when I try to add listener

Tags: java, android

When I try to add a TextChangedListener to my EditText the app crashes, even if I don't write anything inside the AfterTextChangedMethod. I'm trying to get the string inserted by the user, but as soon as I add my listener it crashes.

```
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {

    ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> city_list;

    public MainActivityFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        EditText search = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.search_view);
        search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {    }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {     }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                String inserted = s.toString();
                for(int i=0; i< city_list.size();i++){
                    if(city_list.get(i).toString().equalsIgnoreCase(inserted)){
                        TextView id = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.city_id);
                        id.setText(city_list.get(i).get("_id").toString());
                        TextView lat = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.city_lat);
                        lat.setText(city_list.get(i).get("lat").toString());
                        TextView lon = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.city_long);
                        lon.setText(city_list.get(i).get("lon").toString());
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    }
```

Comment: Post logcat output

Comment: Post Logcat as @RahulGiradkar suggested. Also, please post your .xml code as well - I have a feeling there might be some ClassCastExceptions.

Comment: Use `getView()` instead of `getActivity()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        EditText search = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.search_view);
        search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                String inserted = s.toString();
                for(int i=0; i< city_list.size();i++){
                    if(city_list.get(i).toString().equalsIgnoreCase(inserted)){
                        TextView id = (TextView) view .findViewById(R.id.city_id);
                        id.setText(city_list.get(i).get("_id").toString());
                        TextView lat = (TextView) view .findViewById(R.id.city_lat);
                        lat.setText(city_list.get(i).get("lat").toString());
                        TextView lon = (TextView) view .findViewById(R.id.city_long);
                        lon.setText(city_list.get(i).get("lon").toString());
                    }
                }
            }
        });


        return view;
    }
```

Comment: Still it will be crashed. Because you haven't changed Ids for _TextView_

Comment: @Smerald changed id for text view also

Comment: This will probably solve your problem. Your code tries to access the contents of the main content view before you have created it. The inflate line there creates the view from your xml.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

    EditText search = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.search_view);
    search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            String inserted = s.toString();
            for(int i=0; i< city_list.size();i++){
                if(city_list.get(i).toString().equalsIgnoreCase(inserted)){
                    TextView id = (TextView) view .findViewById(R.id.city_id);
                    id.setText(city_list.get(i).get("_id").toString());
                    TextView lat = (TextView) view .findViewById(R.id.city_lat);
                    lat.setText(city_list.get(i).get("lat").toString());
                    TextView lon = (TextView) getActivity()view .findViewById(R.id.city_long);
                    lon.setText(city_list.get(i).get("lon").toString());
                }
            }
        }
    });


    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View view=    inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        EditText search = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.search_view);
  TextView id = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.city_id);
  TextView lat = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.city_lat);
  TextView lon = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.city_long);
        search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                String inserted = s.toString();
                for(int i=0; i< city_list.size();i++){
                    if(city_list.get(i).toString().equalsIgnoreCase(inserted)){

                      id.setText(city_list.get(i).get("_id").toString());

                       lat.setText(city_list.get(i).get("lat").toString());

                     lon.setText(city_list.get(i).get("lon").toString());
                    }
                }
            }
        });


        return view;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not inflating your view in you onCreateViewMethod first. First Inflate your view and then find sub views.

Answer (score 0):

Your app is crashing because you are trying to add a listener to a null reference object. Double check the ID you are assigning to your editext. Moreover try the below code.

Just return this in your onCreateView Method.

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
```

Override onViewCreated method, use the incoming View variable to initialize your EditText.

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    EditText etSearch = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.search_view);
```

}

Then add textChangeListener to it.

```
   etSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
           //your code here
        }
    });
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

I think you want to use LayoutInflater for your view.

```
LayoutInflater inflater1 = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
EditText search = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.search_view);
```

Then you can override TextChangedMethod method